# Symfony2: Problems with function parameter

Tags: php, oop, symfony, twig

In my template I call a function like this:

```
  loadResults('asc');

  function loadResults(order) {
            return $.get('{{ url('_example_results', { 'order' : ''}) }}'+order, function (html) {
                $('#results').html(html);
            });
        }
```

The function in my controller looks like this:

```
 public function resultsAction($order, Request $request)
 {
      // content is not crucial for solving my problem
 }
```

My results don't get loaded, I get the following error:

```
Controller "...resultsAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$order" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

What adjustments do I need to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because TWIG render the page BEFORE you can act with js, you can't compose the right route with TWIG.
You can archive your problem with two approach:

1) Make the param optional and pass it on query string as follow:

**js**

```
loadResults('asc');

  function loadResults(order) {
            return $.get('{{ url('_example_results') }}'+"?order="order, function (html) {
                $('#results').html(html);
            });
        }
```

**controller**

```
public function resultsAction(Request $request)
 {
      //...
      $order= $request->get('order','asc'); // second parameter is the default if is null 
 }
```

2) Using [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Hope this help